# Cakephp find method produces weird SQL

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to do a Cakephp Find query, and I'm having a little where clausule:

```
$pending = $this->Transaction->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Transaction.amount >' => 'Transaction.recieved')));
```

I'd expect it would generate something like this:

```
SELECT * From `transactions` as `Transaction` WHERE `Transaction`.`amount` > `Transaction`.`recieved`
```

However, it's producing the following SQL:

```
SELECT * From `transactions` as `Transaction` WHERE `Transaction`.`amount` > 'Transaction.recieved'
```

Notice the small difference between

```
`Transaction`.`recieved`
```

and

```
'Transaction.recieved'
```

Why is this? My SQL query is failing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cake has no way of knowing that you didn't intend to use a string (i.e. it's syntactically identical to for example `array( 'Transaction.name' => 'foo' )`). It works if you give the condition as a single string:

```
'conditions' => array( 'Transaction.amount > Transaction.received' )
```